# How to exclude characters from a RegEx pattern with category property codes?

Tags: regex, zend-framework2, pcre, character-properties

There is a number of [category property codes](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/Documentation/pcre/pcrepattern.html#SEC4) (see part "Unicode character properties"), that can be used for a [Perl-compatible Regular Expression (PCRE)](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/Documentation/pcre/index.html)

I defined a regex pattern ([named subpattern](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/Documentation/pcre/pcrepattern.html#SEC14)), that should match letters (`\p{L}`), numbers (`\p{N}`), the space separator (`\p{Zs}`), but also the punctuation (`\p{P}`).

```
(?<sport>[\p{L}\p{N}\p{Zs}\p{P}]*)
```

Since I'm using that for URL routing, the slashes should be excluded. How can I do that?

---

EDIT:

Addtitional information about the context: The pattern is used for a route definition in a Zend Framework 2 module.

**/Catalog/config/module.config.php**

```
<?php
return array(
    ...
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            ...
            'sport' => array(
                'type'  => 'MyNamespace\Mvc\Router\Http\UnicodeRegex',
                'options' => array(
                    'regex' => '/catalog/(?<city>[\p{L}\p{Zs}]*)/(?<sport>[\p{L}\p{N}\p{Zs}\p{P}]*)',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Catalog',
                        'action'     => 'list-courses',
                    ),
                    'spec'  => '/catalog/%city%/%sport%',
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'courses' => array(
                    'type'  => 'segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '[/page/:page]',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Catalog',
                                'action'     => 'list-courses',
                            ),
                        ),
                        'may_terminate' => true,
                    ),
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
    ...
);
```

Comment: Could you add some examples of strings you'd like to apply the regexp to and which results you want to have, please?

Comment: Sure: `Aikido`, `Aerobic, Sportaerobic`. The URI _can_ go on after the sport title (e.g. `Aikido/page/2` or `Aerobic, Sportaerobic/page/2`), so the RegEx parser should make a stop by the slash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *negative look-ahead* to exclude some character from your character set. For your example:

```
(?<sport>(?:(?!/)[\p{L}\p{N}\p{Zs}\p{P}])*)
```

Basically, you will check that the next character is not `/` with *negative look-ahead* `(?!/)`, before proceeding to check whether that character belongs to the character set `[\p{L}\p{N}\p{Zs}\p{P}]`.

PCRE doesn't have set intersection or set difference feature, so this is the work-around for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use it for URL parsing:

According to [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) only `$-_.+!*'(),` are allowed unencoded in an URL¹, so instead of using `\pP` (yes that is allowed instead of `\p{P}`), I suggest you use these characters directly in your regex.

Edit: But if that's not an option, this should be a starting point

```
(?:([\p{L}\p{N}\p{Zs}\p{P}]+?)(?=/|\?|#|$))
```

kind regards,
Tom

¹: Not entirely true, but `/@#;?&=` are only allowed unencoded if they should have their special meaning.

Comment: There are later RFCs that allows for i18n of <s>URL</s> domain name, where Unicode characters are allowed in the URL. Don't know if OP has to process them or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But is there a way to let the pattern so and only exclude the slash? Something like `(?<sport>[\p{L}\p{N}\p{Zs}\p{P}^/]*)`.